# How can I programmatically set the font colour of only one element of a listview?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to change the font colour of a specific item of my listview in code and I am not sure how to approach it. This is what I have so far:

```
lv_options.ItemsSource = new Options[] {
                new Options { Text = "Delete" },
                new Options { Text = "Rename"} ,
                new Options { Text = "Order: Move up" },
                new Options { Text = "Order: Move down"}
            };

            if (act.item.SectionPosition >= act.lst_sections.Count() || act.item.SectionPosition <= 1)
            {
                foreach (Options op in lv_options.ItemsSource)
                {
                    if(op.Text.Equals("Order: Move up"))
                    {
                        lv_options.HeaderTemplate.SetValue....???
                    }
                }

            }
```

This is my listview

```
<ListView x:Name="lv_options">
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
            <ViewCell>
              <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Padding="10, 15, 0, 15">
                <Label Font = "20" Text="{Binding Text}"  />
              </StackLayout>
            </ViewCell>
          </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
      </ListView>
```

Comment: Backgroundcolor or fontcolor?

Comment: font color of the text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to identify which control you want to change.
Then find the control to add the attribute.

Example:
Label label = (Label)ListViewID.FindControl("LabelID");
label.Attributes.Add("color", "red");

Comment: Its on ASP controls but I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
int index = 1;
ListViewItem item = this.lv_options.ItemContainerGenerator.ContainerFromIndex(index) as ListViewItem;
item.Foreground = Brushes.Green;
```

Comment: Please add some details to your answer, such as an explanation of what is wrong in the OP's approach and why your suggestion addresses it.